# How to show grid row value in textBox on SelectionChanged event C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I have to show the grid selected row value into textboxes.I'm using this code, but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 private void CRUD_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtBoxID.Text = CRUD.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxStates.Text = CRUD.SelectedRows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxName.Text = CRUD.SelectedRows[2].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxAddress.Text = CRUD.SelectedRows[3].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxCenter.Text = CRUD.SelectedRows[4].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtBoxCity.Text = CRUD.SelectedRows[5].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What does your data look like in CRUD? What is the bahavior you see? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: @FalcoGer my GridView name is CRUD & it's just a normal person records

Comment: it seems odd to me that you want to use data from different rows and columns. are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @FalcoGer Bro, I just want to click on a row & this should show all the row values to textboxes. I'm doing wrong somewhere.

Comment: That sort of thing is what you should put into your questions.

Comment: Is it winform? Please add accurate tag.

Comment: @qxg Yes bro this is Window Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're indexing your selected rows. if you have less than 6 selected rows, then you will go out of bounds. You probably want to fetch data from only one row. Check if only one row is selected and then use index 0. Make sure you set `CRUD.MultiSelect = false`

Alternatively use `CRUD.CurrentRow` which will only ever get you one row.

Form.Designer.cs:

```
this.CRUD.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.CRUD_SelectionChanged);
```

Form.cs:

```
private void CRUD_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBoxID.Text = CRUD.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    txtBoxStates.Text = CRUD.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    txtBoxName.Text = CRUD.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    txtBoxAddress.Text = CRUD.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    txtBoxCenter.Text = CRUD.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    txtBoxCity.Text = CRUD.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
}
```